# Visual Studio 2017 Database error:"only one statement is allow per batch"

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Visual Studio 2017's SQL Server database and name it as
`MyPushNotification` and encounter an error

> Only one statement is allow per batch

after I enable service broker line.

Below is my SQL Server `CREATE TABLE` statement

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contacts] 
(
    [ContactID]   INT          NOT NULL,
    [ContactName] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [ContactNo]   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [AddedOn]     DATETIME     NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ContactID] ASC)
)

ALTER DATABASE MyPushNotification SET Enable_Broker
```

Comment: what happens if you put a GO statement before the Alter Database?

Comment: If i put a GO statement before the Alter database, it will shows "ERROR SQL70001 THIS STATEMENT IS NOT RECOGNIZED IN THIS CONTEXT"

Comment: I had searched the internet for solution, but everybody says change the SQL script "build action = build"  to "Build action = None", while i do not have any of the SQL script.But thx for the reply anyway Harry.

Comment: https://michaelchu28.wordpress.com/2017/08/22/error-sql71006-only-one-statement-is-allowed-per-batch-a-batch-separator-such-as-go-might-be-required-between-statements/

Answer (score 1):

Put a `;` after the `create table` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contacts] 
(
    [ContactID]   INT          NOT NULL,
    [ContactName] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [ContactNo]   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [AddedOn]     DATETIME     NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ContactID] ASC)
);

ALTER DATABASE MyPushNotification SET Enable_Broker
```

Comment: If I put a ";" after create table statement .It will occur error "Only one statement is allow per batch" at the create table line.

Comment: How do you run this query?

Comment: Normally i will update the table, and execute it, but since i got this error, i cannot update and execute the table.

Comment: hmm?? What do you do with this code? What happens before you see the error message? I mean you have to press a button or something, right?

Comment: sorry, but i don't understand... My question was what tools do you use to run the query? Where do you see the error message?

Comment: @DávidMolnár, are you getting the only one statement allowed error when using SqlDependency for query notification? The query must be a single statement in that case.

Comment: I still don't know what is this question all about. This is why I'm asking what tools is OP using etc. In case of SqlDependency, why would you create the table in the query?